Implementing multi-tenant DynamoDB role-based access control (users, groups)
This is a rather broad architecture question, which should be relevant to quite a few people. Lots of SaaS applications, for example, are multi-tenant and should require RBAC (role based access control).
I want to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel and using known best practices for this. It seems like a common problem and I have found a number of discussions about possible solutions, but none seem to have satisfying resolutions. It would be good to have a generic architecture template for dealing with it, not just for my specific application, as I think there is a broad need.
Project: Think of a multi-tenant CRM application on Amplify Gen2. A DynamoDB pool model for the multi-tenant data. User authentication via Cognito.
Data access needs to be restricted by both tenant and role. Let's say there are admins, employees, customers. Groups may contain any combination of users.
Example tables might include: contact information, notes, communication (chat/messaging), meetings/appointments, business-specific tracking/status (quotes, orders, disputes, etc), and a pseudo-filesystem for arbitrary file uploads/downloads that go to into S3 (via presigned URLs?).
Ideally, it would tie in a customer portal with internal, back office management, so only one front-end interface is needed, with views defined by a role's access (is this a bad idea for some reason?). All of this can be applied across different business verticals/tenants, and the data must remain isolated. The permissions model needs to support groups, to allow people in teams or business units to share access.
Owners (or those with write permissions) should have an option in the UI to update the permissions on any given object. So, for example, if an employee creates a new customer, you can assign Group1 read/write access to it. In turn, Group1 has an owner and some user(s) has read/write permissions on the group itself.
Specific questions:

Is this not possible in a straightforward, built-in way with the latest Cognito/DynamoDB fine grained access controls (see here, see here)? It would be great if it could all be defined in resource.ts. Does it require custom access control logic? If so, is there a recommended way to structure and wrap it?
As I understand, it's recommended to keep permissions separate from data. Is one monolithic table that maps user entities (admins, employees, customer, groups) to item privileges (read/write) the correct approach? See here
If using an architecture such as the one described in #2, is it better to implement the permission table in RDS rather than DynamoDB?
What recommendations can be made for keys, both for security and performance? Is a tenantId recommended as a primary key for some (all?) tables, as that is the first layer of isolation? Maybe a tenantId-shardId? It seems inefficient to apply filters in DynamoDB, so do I need some secondary keys that help to speed up queries with the permissions implemented and perhaps other keys for the business logic?
Is using a custom file table and presigned S3 URLs the best approach for file/document management (possibly with revision tracking)? Is there a better way to do this? Something seems off about needing to do a custom implementation of this from the ground up. Would this be better in RDS than DynamoDB?
Is there a reason that a single UI can't, or shouldn't, be shared among the different roles? One unified UI seems easier to maintain, as well as being more appealing for marketing, and it simplifies documentation.
Will I need to discard all built-in DynamoDB user access controls to implement my own layer (and wrap it in something)? If so, is there a recommended way to do this? Do I just make some packaged code? Some sort of service (API, Lambda)?
Am I missing anything obvious?

Currently, I am not using GraphQL (is there any reason to add that layer?), and I think that is the more generically applicable case. I only skimmed answers to similar questions that rely on GraphQL, but none jumped out at me as ideal solutions.
Some other decent references for efficient DynamoDB designs:

https://aws.amazon.com/tutorials/design-a-database-for-a-mobile-app-with-dynamodb/module-2/
https://dev.to/aws-builders/dynamodb-data-modeling-an-effective-way-to-start-22e9

